# Database-Driven Select Form (Drop Down) Block in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms

I'm completely new to Drupal, forgive me for any horrible assumptions/falsehoods I make in my question.

I'm trying to add a database-driven drop-down box to my sidebar. I'm currently doing this by creating a custom block (is that even the right approach?). Currently, when I can even get the block to render at all, it just shows the word "Array", rather than the contents. I've tested the output of my "getGames" function and the array is populated correctly.

Here is the current code:

```
<?php
$games_array = getGames();

return drupal_get_form('gamesForm', $games_array);

function getGames()
{
    $query = "SELECT ID, Name FROM drupGN.Game ORDER BY Name;";
    $results =  db_query($query);

    foreach ($results as $item) {
        $key = $item->ID;
        $value = $item->Name;
        $games_array[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $games_array;
}

function gamesForm($form_state, $games_array)
{
    $form['games'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Game Name',
        '#options' => $games_array,
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    return $form;
}
?>
```

Like I said, the database connection is working, and the $games_array data is successfully populated. It's just the form display that appears to be not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
return drupal_get_form('gamesForm', $games_array);
```

with

```
return drupal_render(drupal_get_form('gamesForm', $games_array));
```

As you haven't mentioned your Drupal version, and you said you are seeing "Array" in the block, my best guessing is that your Drupal version is 7. Drupal 7 forms need drupal_render to be called somewhere (it happens automatically on page callbacks but not in blocks). So that's why you are seeing the "Array" word there.

This is not the correct approach FYI. You can easily write a custom function that defines a new block and its block_view functions. and you can even make a page/block combo with module approach.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I figured my approach was invalid, the custom block editor was just the first place I saw that I could use custom code, so I put it there.

Where would I define custom functions (yes, I'm using Drupal 7)? I'm still not sure what the best way is to integrate custom code with the built-in content creation tools.

Comment: you are welcome :) anyway, don't forget to add your Drupal version in post related Drupal interns. Good luck!